# Wrong library version when moving web application from Tomcat to WebLogic

Tags: web, weblogic, java

My java web application was working on Apache Tomcat. It needs some third party libraries for its work (jasperreports 3.7.2 in particular). But now it became necessary to move application on WebLogic. And it appears that it uses not the library it was using before (on Tomcat) but some other version of this library (I suspect that one which comes with WebLogic by default). How can i specify concrete version of library  and make WebLogic use it? I've never used weblogic before. May be i should type something in deployment descriptors or something like that? Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Did you bring jasper reports in yourself?  Have you altered the classloading sequence?

Comment: I don't really understand the first question. As i understand the jasperreports library is situated in WEB-INF/lib folder inside war archive. I didn't alter the classloading sequence.

Comment: jasperreports is not part of Weblogic by default. are you getting any error liek a ClassNotFoundExcpetion or NoClassDefFoundError ?

Comment: If there is only ONE jasperreports.jar in the Tomcat AND the WebLogic installation (search the file system) then your deployment scheme is apparently broken.

Comment: It could be that jasperreport itself uses library that is WebLogic standart library. I mean that the problem is not necessary in jasperreports, but it seems that problem is in library versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the JAR you want inside WEB-INF/lib in your war, you can tell Weblogic to use that jar over any other jar that might be present in the Classloader.

- Use the [prefer-web-inf-classes](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/programming/classloading.html#wp1082452) element in a `weblogic.xml` Web application deployment descriptor (that goes in WEB-INF next to the `web.xml`)

Here is an example weblogic.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app
 xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90 http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90/weblogic- web-app.xsd">
    <container-descriptor>
        <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
     </container-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

Note: In this usage all WEB_INF/lib classes will be preferred over other versions in the classpath.